# Radio Buttons, multidimensional arrays and PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have created a form that allows someone to create a quiz, all of the questions and the answers are stored in a database. You can see a simplified version of the form here:

http://jsfiddle.net/superuntitled/uaTtx/4/

Each question can have an infinite number of answers and only one answer can be correct. To denote the 'correct' answer, I am using radio buttons.

The problem that I am having is that only the selected radio button passes a value to my php code, see a sample `$_POST` array of values (in this example, three answers for the question "What is a space station?"):

```
[text] => Array
    (
        [0] => A cosmic hotel
        [1] => An interstellar depot
        [2] => A closet organizer
    )

[correct] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
```

Even if the correct answer was "An interstellar depot", the first answer "A cosmic hotel" will be entered as the correct answer when I loop through this `$_POST` array. This is because only a selected radio button will pass a value.

My radio input looks like this:

```
<input  type="radio" name="answer[1][correct][]" value="1" />
```

The first set of brackets denotes the question it is associated with, and this number is incremented with each new question.

Does anyone have any ideas on how set the correct answer properly?

Comment: Your linked example is too short and simplified to clear up the use case. (I'd like to know why this question was downvoted though.)

Comment: I think if you change `name="answer[1][correct][]"` to `name="answer[1][correct]"`, you'll be able to handle it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I get it now. But I'm afraid there is no easy solution to your problem.

While the `..[]` syntax works for collecting the text fields in an array, there is no **correlation between text inputs and radio inputs**. You have to manually name the text fields `answer[1][text][235]` and the radios `answer[1][correct][235]`.

This requires an enumeration loop for the PHP output. And also obviously that the DHTML/AJAX "Add another answer/question" function has to parse the existing fields, and count the last number up.

If you want to retain the lazy solution, then you have to use `type=checkbox` instead of `type=radio`. That's the only way to have all fields present at submission, so the automatic `...[]` enumeration works for text fields and checkboxes.
You could use some DHTML/Javascript trickery there to ensure that only one checkbox per group is selected at any time. (= fake radio buttons)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, radio buttons only submit the checked value, that's the point.

Make your inputs like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="answer[1][correct]" value="1" />
```

Then you'll get arrays like this:

```
'answer' => array(
    1 => array(
        'text' => array( … ),
        'correct' => 1
    )
)
```

And the correct answer is easily picked with:

```
$array['answer'][1]['text'][$array['answer'][1]['correct']]
```

Comment: thanks deceze, now when I check for `$_POST['answer'][$num]['correct']`, they are all getting saved with a value of '1'

Comment: @super Are you putting different values into them? I.e. you have one radio button with `value="0"`, one with `value="1"` etc. The value should be the number of the correct answer, it does **not** just mean "checked" or "unchecked".

Comment: I am not using different values. the interface allows for the answers to be re-ordered, so setting the value of the correct radio button may not always be correct. thank you for helping me with this. I have been trying to sort out an answer for this for weeks.

Comment: @super I'm afraid you'll have to find a way to uniquely id each answer and use that id as a value for your radio buttons.

Comment: thank you for your help, I will work on a new solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply make a hidden form field that has the correct answer as its value and then check whether the value of a selected radio button is equal to that hidden input value?

For example:

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="correct_answer" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="1" /> #1
    <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="2" /> #2
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I'm thinking that would solve your problem. You would need to check the value of the radio button against the value of the hidden form field. If they're the same, it's correct. Else, it's incorrect.

Hope that helps.